# I can't install anything with apt-get on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

The first problem is that I can't even post my question on askUbuntu!

Second, my problem is, I can't install anything since a while via `apt-get`, I suspect it happened when I tried to install Deeping desktop a couple of days ago, I modified the repositories somewhere and I forgot where, and compiz is causing the problem. I tried all what I found here, but nothing worked. I found this:

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old
mkdir -p lists/partial
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

But, it didn't work.

Here's what I get, when I try to install JAI for example:

```
sudo apt-get install libjai-core-java

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 compiz : Depends: compiz-core (>= 1:0.9.11.2+14.04.20140714-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: compiz-plugins-default (>= 1:0.9.11.2+14.04.20140714-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: compiz-gnome but it is not going to be installed
 libcompizconfig0 : Depends: compiz-core (= 1:0.9.11.2+14.04.20140714-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Afterwards, when I use `apt-get -f install`, I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas accountsservice-ubuntu-touch-schemas
  android-tools-adb automoc checkbox-ng checkbox-ng-service click-dev
  click-doc debootstrap eclipse-platform-data eclipse-rcp
  gsettings-ubuntu-touch-schemas kdelibs5-dbg kdepim-mobileui-data ktouch-data
  libandroid-properties1 libastro1 libcommons-cli-java libcommons-dbcp-java
  libcommons-lang-java libcommons-pool-java libcomposereditorng4
  libcontent-hub0 libdbus-cpp2 libequinox-osgi-java
  libfelix-bundlerepository-java libfelix-gogo-command-java
  libfelix-gogo-runtime-java libfelix-gogo-shell-java libfelix-osgi-obr-java
  libgeronimo-jta-1.1-spec-java libgflags2 libgles2-mesa-dev libglib2.0-dev
  libgoogle-glog0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libhud2
  libhybris-common1 libicu4j-4.4-java libkimproxy4 libkutils4
  libkwinactiveeffects1abi4 libkwinactiveglesutils1 libkwinactiveglutils1abi3
  libkxml2-java liblsofui4 libmaliit-plugins0 libmarblewidget18
  libmediascanner-2.0-0 libmirplatform libmirplatformgraphics-mesa
  libmirserver18 libofono-qt1 libonline-accounts-client1 liboxideqtcore0
  libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libphonon-dev libpresage-data libpresage1
  libqdjango-db0 libqextserialport1 libqmenumodel0 libqt4-dbg libqt5feedback5
  libqt5multimedia5-plugins libqt5positioning5 libqt5positioning5-plugins
  libqt5qml-graphicaleffects libqt5sensors5-dev libqt5systeminfo5
  libqtlocation1 libquazip0 libshp1 libsoprano-dev libswt-cairo-gtk-3-jni
  libswt-glx-gtk-3-jni libswt-gnome-gtk-3-jni libswt-gtk-3-java
  libswt-gtk-3-jni libswt-webkit-gtk-3-jni libsystemsettings1 libthumbnailer0
  libtomcat7-java libubuntu-application-api-mirserver1
  libubuntu-download-manager-client0 libubuntu-download-manager-common0
  libubuntu-download-manager-priv0 libubuntu-location-service0
  libubuntu-platform-hardware-api1 libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0 libunity-action-qt1
  libunity-mir1 libunwind8 libusermetricsinput1 libusermetricsoutput1
  libwlocate0 libxslt1-dev marble-data marble-plugins mediascanner2.0
  packagekit-tools plainbox-provider-checkbox
  plainbox-provider-resource-generic plainbox-secure-policy presage
  python3-checkbox-ng python3-checkbox-support python3-gnupg python3-plainbox
  python3-pyparsing python3-requests python3-urllib3 qmenumodel-qml qmlscene
  qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common qtdeclarative4-kqtquickcharts-1
  qtdeclarative5-dee-plugin qtdeclarative5-doc-html
  qtdeclarative5-qtfeedback-plugin qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-systeminfo-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-settings-components-assets
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1
  qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin-assets
  qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-notifications-plugin
  qtmultimedia5-doc-html qtpositioning5-dev qtscript5-doc-html qtsvg5-doc-html
  qtwebkit5-doc-html sat4j schroot schroot-common suru-icon-theme
  system-image-common system-image-dbus thumbnailer-service
  ubuntu-download-manager ubuntu-html5-theme ubuntu-html5-ui-toolkit
  ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-purchase-service ubuntu-touch-sounds
  ubuntu-ui-toolkit-doc ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme ubuntuone-credentials-common
  unity-action-doc unity-plugin-scopes unity-scope-mediascanner2
  unity-scope-scopes usermetricsservice
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  compiz
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libcompizconfig0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  compiz
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 189 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 2,348 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin/ trusty/main compiz i386 1:0.9.99-4+git20140707164843~2e85d002e7 [2,348 kB]
Fetched 2,348 kB in 2min 5s (18.8 kB/s)                                        
(Reading database ... 472782 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../compiz_1%3a0.9.99-4+git20140707164843~2e85d002e7_i386.deb ...
Unpacking compiz (1:0.9.99-4+git20140707164843~2e85d002e7) over (1:0.9.11.2+14.04.20140714-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/compiz_1%3a0.9.99-4+git20140707164843~2e85d002e7_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/compiz/ccp.xml', which is also in package libcompizconfig0 1:0.9.11.2+14.04.20140714-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/compiz_1%3a0.9.99-4+git20140707164843~2e85d002e7_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

P.S.I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Gnome/KDE as desktop environments.

Comment: Off-topic, try http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: what's the problem with posting on askUnuntu?

Comment: @YuHao That's why I said I have a problem with AskUbuntu.

Comment: @yefrem Whenever I click on "Post Your Question" button, I get this error message:     
You can only post once every 20 minutes.
You can only ask 6 questions in a 24-hour period.
I posted only one question on AskUbuntu, and it was 3 days ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. 
I replaced **Saucy** by **trusty** in

> /etc/apt/sources.list

[image]

Comment: You are Life savior !! Thanks that's worked, can you explain what that  changes meant?